# IDEA 13 regex checker in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

There is cool feature in IDEA to check your regex in Java.
When you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> over your selected pattern, you get:

[image: image link]

And if you choose *Check RegExp*, you get something like this:

[image: image link]

But if you try same thing using Scala there is no *Check RegExp* option. I've tried hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for each of following lines of code:

```
val myRegex = """\w""".r
val myRegex2:Pattern = Pattern.compile("""\w""")
val myregex3 = new Regex("""\w""")
```

but no *Check RegExp* option showed. Any idea how to "enable" this feature to work with Scala?

Comment: I think this is because language injection is disabled by default for Scala files for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the tip of @ziggystar, if you have the IntelliLang plugin installed, you can "inject" Regex  syntax into a string. There is a message though stating that the injection was temporary, and the injection doesn't survive IntelliJ restart.

[image: Injection screenshot]

Comment: thanks, that'll do:D, but is there any way for this working automatically?